# Certain configuration options not appearing in API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've watched a couple videos that go into the "Integration Request" option for a REST API endpoint. It seems like they get configuration options/selections that I can't see. Does anyone know why this is the case? I will attach screenshots. Video is the top picture mine is bottom. [image] [image]

Comment: What options are missing exactly?

Comment: The dropdown selections 'URL Path Parameters", "URL Query String Parameters", "HTTP Headers", and "Mapping Templates"

Answer (score 0):

These options are **not available** in [lambda proxy intergration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) which you are using. Video clearly is not using that integration type.